# Adding HugeInteger String Objects

Tags: c++, string

Basically, this problem is supposed to create a class HugeInteger that uses a string to store digits. I have to add HugeInteger objects. The program works when I add small integers (ie. 3 4), however, when I ran the program and input 2 values (ie. 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1), the program appears to freeze and not displaying anything. Would appreciate some help.Thanks in advance.

Here's my code.

HugeInteger.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

class HugeInteger
{
    // need to offer friendship to these 2 functions
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & src, HugeInteger & value);
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & dest, const HugeInteger & value);

public:
    //ctor that converts a "long long" into a HugeInteger
    HugeInteger(long long value = 0LL); //0LL is constant literal value 0
    //   of type long long

    //ctor that converts a string into a HugeInteger
    HugeInteger(const char *str);

    //Convert a string into a HugeInteger
    void input(const std::string& str);

    //adds RHS into LHS (the object pointed to by the "this" pointer) and returns result
    HugeInteger & operator +=(const HugeInteger & RHS);

    //adds a "long long" (RHS) and LHS and puts result into a temp HugeInteger
    //   and returns result
    HugeInteger operator +(long long RHS) const;

    //adds a string (which will be converted into a HugeInteger) with LHS into a temp 
    //       HugeInteger and returns result
    HugeInteger operator +(const char * RHS) const;

    // overload preincrement operator for the HugeInteger class
    HugeInteger & operator ++ (void);

    // overload postincrement operator for the HugeInteger class
    HugeInteger operator ++ (int);

private:
    bool negative;  // will be true if number is negative
    std::string hugeInt; // each digit is stored in a string object
};

//overloads the << and >> operators for the HugeInteger class
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & src, HugeInteger & value);
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & dest, const HugeInteger & value);
```

HugeInteger.cpp

```
#include "HugeInteger.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HugeInteger::HugeInteger(long long value)
{
    // set all MaxDigit digits to zero to start
    this->negative = false;
    if (value < 0LL){ // 0LL is constant literal 0 of type long long
        this->negative = true;
        value = -value; // make the value positive                  
    }

    unsigned int i = 0;


    for (; i < hugeInt.size(); i++)
    {
        this->hugeInt[i] = '0';
    }
    this->hugeInt[i] = '\0';



    // convert individual digits of input value into a HugeInteger
    for (unsigned int j = hugeInt.size() - 1; j >= 0 && value != 0LL; j--)
    {
        short result = value % 10;
        char c = (char)result;
        this->hugeInt[j] = c;
        value /= 10;
    }

    // test to make sure that HugeInteger was able to contain value

    if (value != 0LL){
        *this = 0LL; // set to -0, to signal overflow
        this->negative = true; //   Possibly should increase value assigned
    }                          //   to MaxDigit to fix this problem.
}

// converts string into a HugeInteger object
HugeInteger::HugeInteger(const char *str)
{
    this->input(str);
}

// converts long long into HugeInteger and then invokes
//    HugeInteger::operator +=(const HugeInteger & )
HugeInteger HugeInteger::operator +(long long value) const
{
    HugeInteger temp = *this;
    return temp += (HugeInteger(value));
}


//converts string into HugeInteger and then invokes
//   HugeInteger::operator +=(const HugeInteger & )
HugeInteger HugeInteger::operator +(const char *str) const
{
    HugeInteger temp = *this;
    return temp += (HugeInteger(str));
}

// Adds into the HugeInteger pointed to by the "this" pointer 
//   the HugeInteger op.
//   Then the calculated result is returned
HugeInteger & HugeInteger::operator+=(const HugeInteger &op)
{

    int value = atoi(op.hugeInt.c_str());

    for (int i = value - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        this->operator++();
    }

    return *this;
}



void HugeInteger::input(const std::string& str)
{
    // assume positive for now
    this->negative = false;

    // init. to all zeros first
    unsigned int i = 0;

    this->hugeInt.clear();

    while (i < str.size())
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            this->hugeInt += str[i];
        i++;
    }
}

// Pre-increment operator
HugeInteger & HugeInteger::operator ++ ()
{
    string key = this->hugeInt;

    istringstream in(key);
    int int_key;
    in >> int_key;
    int_key++;
    ostringstream out;
    out << int_key;
    key = out.str();
    this->hugeInt = key;

    return *this;
}

// Post-increment operator
HugeInteger HugeInteger::operator ++ (int)
{
    string key = this->hugeInt;

    istringstream in(key);
    int int_key;
    in >> int_key;
    int_key++;
    ostringstream out;
    out << int_key;
    key = out.str();
    HugeInteger temp = *this;
    this->hugeInt = key;

    return temp;
}

istream & operator>>(istream & input, HugeInteger & value)
{
    string inputString;
    input >> inputString;
    value.input(inputString);
    return input;
}

ostream & operator << (ostream & output, const HugeInteger & value)
{
    // find first non-zero digit
    unsigned int i = 0;

    if (value.hugeInt.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << '0';
    }

    while (i < value.hugeInt.size()){
        if (value.hugeInt[i] != '0'){
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // if all zeros, just output a single 0
    if (i == 40)
    {
        cout << '0';
        return output;
    }

    // check if we need to ouput a negative sign
    if (value.negative){
        cout << '-';
    }

    // output remaining digits
    for (; i < value.hugeInt.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << value.hugeInt[i];
    }

    return output;
}
```

MainProgram

```
#include "HugeInteger.h" // include definiton of class HugeInteger
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HugeInteger A, B, C, D;

    // input value for A & B
    cout << "****** Test << & >> operators ******\n\n";
    cout << "Input values for A and B: ";
    cin >> A >> B;
    cout << "\nA = " << A << "\nB = " << B;

    D = B;

    // test += operator
    cout << "\n\n****** Test += operator ******\n\n";
    cout << "A = " << A << "\nB = " << B << "\nC = " << C << "\n\n";
    cout << "C = B += A\n";
    C = B += A;
    cout << "\nA = " << A << "\nB = " << B << "\nC = " << C;
    B = D;  // restore B's value

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: It doesn't respond because? It can be that your system just can't handle the load.

Comment: It responds it just suffers from overflow for that combination.

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious architectural problems, unfortunately. The biggest problem is that your addition algorithm performs addition by looping over the `++` increment operator.

Here's a walkthrough of what happens during addition of `C = A + B`:

- The `+` operator just defers to the `+=` operator, which is fine.
- Then the `+=` operator converts the string representation of `B` into an integer using `atoi`. **This is the first problem: if HugeInt is meant to hold integers larger than `int` can hold, then converting to `int` isn't probably the right way to do this!**
- Then the actual addition is done by performing the `++` operator `B` times. **If you expect the numbers to be large then this will be a very inefficient step. I recommend you investigate a better addition algorithm!**
- In the `++` operator, you create an input stringstream and an output stringstream so that you can convert the string representation of `A` into an `int`, increment the `int`, and then convert back to a string to store. Just like my comment on the `+=` operator, **converting to `int` is inappropriate when your HugeInt stores a number that is larger than the largest `int`.**

To be honest, though, I'm not sure that for that particular combination you should experience a freeze unless there's some undefined behaviour for converting a string that is too long into an integer. But I would recommend you come up with a storage mechanism and addition algorithm that doesn't require you to convert to `int`, since that defeats the point of the `HugeInt` class in the first place.